# Is there a reason to specify an alias the same as the real name?

Tags: mysql, alias

Why would anyone ever bother typing the same name as the alias?

```
SELECT * FROM node
INNER JOIN users users
  ON node.uid = users.uid
INNER JOIN node node2
  ON node.uid = node2.uid
INNER JOIN mytable mytable
  ON node2.nid = mytable.nid
```

(Edited to show a simple example of where an alias seems unnecessary)

Comment: The author probably would like to join the same table later, so they can do `users2`, `users3` etc.

Comment: I do this for just that reason.

Comment: If that's all the SQL then I'd guess cargo-cult programming: the author saw aliases in use somewhere else and blindly copied the pattern without understand it. Can you provide more context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only think that this is because of some auto-generated query or someone that doesn't know what they are doing.

There's no value in doing this, even if you were joining the same table later because then you'd only need the second instance to be aliased.